# Lambda function with groupby and condition issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to see how to express counts of unique values of column B for each unique value in column A where corresponding column C >0.

df:

```
A    B     C
1    10    0
1    12    3
2    3     1
```

I tried this but its missing the where clause to filter for C>0. How do I add it?

```
df.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply(lambda b : b.astype(int).nunique())
```

Comment: `df[df['C'].gt(0)].groupby('A')['B'].nuniques()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I am not sure how your code will return where C is greater than 0. Can you double check?

Comment: `df['C'].gt(0)`, `gt` stands for greater than.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first start by creating the dataframe that OP mentions in the question

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2], 'B': [10,12,3], 'C': [0,3,1]})
```

Now, in order to achieve what OP wants, there are various options. One of the ways is by selecting the `df` where column `C` is `greater than 0`, then use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by column `A`. Finally, use [`pandas.DataFrame.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) to count the unique values of column B. In one line it would look like the following

```
count = df[df['C'] > 0].groupby('A')['B'].nunique()

[Out]:
A
1    1
2    1
```

If one wants to sum every number in of unique items that satisfy the condition, from the dataframe `count`, one can simply do

```
count = count.sum()

[Out]:
2
```

Assuming one wants to do everything in one line, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) as

```
count = df[df['C'] > 0].groupby('A')['B'].nunique().sum()

[Out]:
2
```